# Making input box so that user can put his/her name and be used in every msg box

Tags: excel, vba

so i would like to ask how to make an inputbox and use the result/input for my messageboxes so that instead of having the usual "Hello User", it would be their name. this was my attempt

```
Sub WorksheetActivate()
Dim Msg
Msg = "please enter your name"

 If ActiveSheet("Sheet1").Select Then
    InputBox(msg,"dear user")
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code can't possibly compile, or run, for several reasons.

---

> ```
> If ActiveSheet("Sheet1").Select Then
> ```

`ActiveSheet` is a global-scope object that represents, well, *the active sheet*. If you want to work with `Sheet1`, then work with `Sheet1`:

```
If Sheet1.[...] Then
```

If `Sheet1` doesn't exist at compile-time, you need to retrieve it from a `Workbook` object:

```
If ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").[...] Then
```

`.Select` is a `Sub` procedure that *selects the specified sheet*. It doesn't return anything. `If ... Then` requires a *Boolean expression*, so your code would only be legal if `.Select` returned a `Boolean`, or a value that could be implicitly converted into one.

Except, you're *already* in a worksheet module's code-behind: you *presumably* want to be working with *that* sheet. If that's the case, then you don't need to do anything: the sheet was just activated (because you're handling the `Activate` event), so it *is* the `ActiveSheet` and you don't need to `Select` it anyway; you can use `Me` to refer to that sheet:

```
Me.Range("A1").Value = 42
```

---

> ```
> Sub WorksheetActivate()
> ```

Worksheet events (*all* events, actually) follow a very specific naming scheme for their handlers:

```
Private Sub EventSource_EventName()
```

As it stands, `WorksheetActivate` is just another (implicitly) `Public` procedure that can by invoked from anywhere - but it won't handle the `Activate` event of any worksheet, because its *signature* doesn't match that of the handler for the `Activate` event of the `Worksheet` interface.

Never type event handler signatures by hand: the signature must match *exactly*, including the parameters (the names don't matter, but the ordering and the types do).

Instead, pay attention to the two dropdowns at the top of the code pane. The left-most dropdown says `(General)`; click it, and select `Worksheet`. That will either create a new handler for some default event, or take you to it if it already exists. Now while the left-side dropdown says `Worksheet`, look at what's in the other dropdown: every event exposed by the `Worksheet` interface is there! Pick one, and the editor automatically generates the handler procedure, with the correct signature.

> ```
> InputBox(msg,"dear user")
> ```

That line of code actually looks like this in the editor:

```
InputBox (msg,"dear user")
```

Notice the whitespace between `InputBox` and the argument list: that's the editor telling you "I'm going to take everything between these parentheses, evaluate it as an expression, and pass it `ByVal` to the procedure". And since `(msg, "dear user")` isn't an expression that can be evaluated, the code fails to compile.

If you didn't care for the function's return value (i.e. the user's input), you could simply drop the parentheses:

```
InputBox msg, "dear user"
```

But you *do* care for it - you want to reuse that input *somewhere, later on*. Declare a variable to hold that value, *at module scope* so every single procedure in that module can see it:

```
Private UserName As String
```

Now you're going to assign that variable with the return value of the `InputBox` function:

```
UserName = InputBox(msg, "dear user")
```

Notice the editor doesn't put a whitespace between `InputBox` and `(` now.

And now you can refer to `UserName` anywhere in that worksheet's code-behind, to use the value that the user provided the last time the sheet was activated.

Note that `Worksheet_Activate` will run *every time* the sheet is activated. So you can make the `InputBox` conditional to `UserName` being empty:

```
If UserName = vbNullString Then
    UserName = InputBox(...)
End If
```

---

Lastly, note that `Application.UserName` would return the user name that Excel itself is using:

```
MsgBox "Hi, " & Application.UserName
```

That value is used to identify the author of the document when you save the workbook, for example.

You could also use the Windows login user name, using the `Environ$` function and the `USERNAME` variable:

```
MsgBox "Hi, " & Environ$("USERNAME")
```

Rule of thumb, avoid prompting the user for input you can get by other means.

Comment: @Kurt every sheet in `ThisWorkbook` (the one that contains the VBA project) that exists at compile-time has a *code name*. Select the sheet in the *project explorer* (ctrl+r) then set its `(Name)` property to a meaningful name (f4) - then use that identifier as-is in your code wherever you need to refer to it, e.g. `Sheet1.Range("A1").Value`

Comment: there were no errors in the code, but mine doesnt work? can i see how you did it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code on the worksheet you want to trigger the pop up:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()


    MsgBox ("dear " & Application.UserName) 'this will work if the username that logs is the user name


End Sub
```